# Necessary and Sufficient Condition of Inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

So suppose I have the condition $$a > b\cos(x)$$ where $a>0,b\geq0$ and $\forall x \in [0,2\pi[$. Then can be say that the above condition is satisfied **if and only if** $$a > b$$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried plugging in a few values? What about when $\cos(x)\le0$?

Comment: @copper.hat: That condition is not allowed. $a>0$ and $b \ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat $a$ is required to be positive.

Comment: Oops. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Does the first condition hold for all $x$ or a specific $x$?

Comment: It should hold for all $x$

Comment: I'm just confused on the **iff** condition...it should hold for both ways, right?

Comment: @JohnnyQue If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$ For $x \in [0, 2 \pi]$. Multiply this inequality by any $b \ge 0$ and you get

$$ -b \le b \cos(x) \le b$$

It's an if and only if statement so break it up into two cases.

**Case 1:** If $a > b$, then $a > b \cos(x)$ from the above inequality.

**case 2:** If $a > b \cos(x)$ for a given $x \in [0, 2 \pi]$, would you expect $a > b$ to hold? Of course not! Because $\cos(x) = 0$ when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so at this particular $x$, you could take *any* $b > a$, and the first inequality would be satisfied. For example,

$1 > 2 \cos(\pi/2)$, but $1 < 2$.

so, in general, this direction fails to hold.

---

**Edit:**

You have now made it clear that you meant $ a > b \cos(x) \iff a > b$ for *all* $x \in [0, 2 \pi]$. This changes things, as it then must hold for $x = 0$, so that

$$a > b \cos(0) = b$$

This fact did not change case 1, so we can conclude it is both a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: So your saying it's only a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1):

For $b=0$

$a > b\cos x=0$ is true  $\forall x$.

Let $b> 0$

$$a>b \implies \frac{a}{b}>1\geq \cos x \quad \forall x$$

Thus for $a>0$ and $b\geq 0$:

> $$a > b\cos x \quad \forall x \iff b=0 \quad \lor \quad a>b>0 \iff a>b$$

Comment: This is wrong. Particularly the step from $\cos x<\frac ab$ to $\forall x\iff a>b$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Maybe it's trivial but really I can't see the point. Could you please explain better.$cosx \leq 1< \frac{a}{b}$  isn't it true for all x?

Comment: What if $\cos x<1$? Then we can have $a=b$. What if $\cos x\le0$? Then we can have $a<b$. As you can see, there are some holes in your arguments.

Comment: Ok now I got ypur point, I think I've used $\iff$ in a improper way. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't very clear. My interpretation is that $a>b\cos x$ for some $x\in[0,2\pi[$, not for all $x$.

Comment: But it seems this was mentioned in the comments, so I'm gonna edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Could you please verify my answer now! Thanks.

Comment: It seems fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If $a>b\cos x$ for all $x\in[0,2\pi[$ then choosing $x=0$ shows that $a>b$.

If $a>b\ge0$ then, since $\cos x\le1$, $b\ge b\cos x$ for all $x$ and so $a>b\cos x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Let $x=\pi$, $a=1$, $b=2$.